# $attribute_string = $this->product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code') returns null

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

why the following code:

```
$attribute_string = $this->product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code');
```

gives me null although the attribute exist.

and following code:

```
$attribute_string = $this->product->getAttributeText('layeredmake')
```

gives me false

Comment: what is the type of attribute_code, I mean is it dropdown or simple text?

Comment: @Ramkishan it's multiple select

Answer (score 0):

Is this on product listing (category view, search result page)? 
If so you need to set the `Used in product listing` field to `Yes`

Go to Stores > Attributes > Product, open attribute `layeredmake`, open the 'Storefront Properties' and check the aforementioned field.

Then you should also be able to get the value the following way:

```php
$attribute_string = $product->getLayeredmake();
```

If this is the case of a product page, then make sure your indexers are up to date and that the product actually has a value for the specific store view.

Comment: it still returns null

Comment: @YomnaMansour if you haven't you should still reindex and flush the cache. `bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute` and  `bin/magento cache:flush`